# Compare values in two lists and return the similar or nearest value from a third list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, math

I will like to find similar values of j in v and return x. when the value in j is not equal to v, I will like the code the detect the 2 value in v that j values between. so if j falls between v1 and v2, I will like the code to return `max(x1,x2)- ( ((j-v1)/(v2-v1))*(max(x1,x2)-min(x1,x2)))`

```
v= [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100]
x= [67,56,89,21,90,54,38,93,46,17,75]
j= [200,300,400,460,500,600,700,800,870,900,950]

for i in range(len(v)-1):
    if v[i] > j and V[i+1] < j:
        p = max(x[i],x[i+1])- ( ((j-v[i])/(v[i+1]-v[i]))*(max(x[i],x[i+1])-min(x[i],x[i+1])))
    elif v[i] ==j:
        b= x[i]
print(p,b)

"""
n = [x[i] for i, v_ele in enumerate(v) if v_ele in j]
p=  [x[i] for i, v_ele in enumerate(v) if v_ele > j and v_ele 
print(n)
"""
```

I will like my answers to return

```
[56,89,21,48.6,90,54,38,93,60.1,46,31.5]
```

Comment: so what's your current output?

Comment: The code doesn't work it returns syntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Sure it does, you're missing a colon here: `if v[i] > j and V[i+1] < j` (besides, `V` and `v` are not the same name in Python)

Comment: The code has a type error. 'TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this using the following two helper functions. Note that I think there may be a slight error for the fourth element in your expected output in the question - I get that value as `62.4` while you have `48.6`.

**Code:**

```
def get_v_indx(j_ele, v):
    if j_ele in v:
        return v.index(j_ele)
    else:
        for i, ele in enumerate(v):
            if ele > j_ele:
                return i-1+(j_ele-v[i-1])/(ele-v[i-1])

def get_x_ele(i, x):
    try:
        return x[i]
    except TypeError:
        return x[int(i)] + (x[int(i)+1]-x[int(i)])*(i-int(i))
```

**Usage:**

```
>>> [get_x_ele(get_v_indx(j_ele, v), x) for j_ele in j]
[56, 89, 21, 62.4, 90, 54, 38, 93, 60.1, 46, 31.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a couple of problems with your code:

First, after your if statement, there is a colon missing and one of your "v"s is capitalized. Computers are unforgiving - no typo's! ;)

Then, in that same line, you try to compare an integer (`v[i]` and `v[i+1]`) with a complete list of integers (`j`). Instead you need to go through your j list and compare each element in that list. I introduced an index `ij` for going through j.

When you compare that j value to v, you got your >< signs mixed up. Since your v list is ordered from small to big, it is impossible to be smaller than element i and simultaneously bigger than element i+1. ;)

Lastly, I'm not sure why you would store your value in two different variables (p and b) instead of the same. I did just that and called it a and printed it in an example alongside the j value it comes from.

```
v= [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100]
x= [67,56,89,21,90,54,38,93,46,17,75]
j= [200,300,400,460,500,600,700,800,870,900,950]

for ij in range(len(j)): 
    for i in range(len(v)-1): 
        if v[i] < j[ij] and v[i+1] > j[ij]: 
            a = max(x[i],x[i+1])- ( ((j[ij]-v[i])/(v[i+1]-v[i]))*(max(x[i],x[i+1])-min(x[i],x[i+1]))) 
        elif v[i] == j[ij]: 
            a = x[i] 
 print(j[ij]," leads to ",a)
```

Output:

```
200  leads to  56
300  leads to  89
400  leads to  21
460  leads to  48.6
500  leads to  90
600  leads to  54
700  leads to  38
800  leads to  93
870  leads to  60.1
900  leads to  46
950  leads to  31.5
```